# How to format date in Python and avoid XLDateAmbiguous and fix leap year

Tags: python, datetime

I have an odd error raised in a script.

```
XLDateAmbiguous: 15.0
```

I have tried formatting the date as such:

```
sOutput += datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(value, workbook.datemode)).strftime(sDateTimeFormat)
```

but i am still recieving the same error, any help in any way is very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function) are very clear about when this is raised.

It will happen if the `workbook.datemode == 0` and `1.0 <= value < 61.0`

Comment: How can this answer be accepted, when no one says how to read the data?